# Texture mapping does not work correctly using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping, opengl-3

The goal of my program is to mix the video stream from my Kinect with a simple triangle using OpenGL. To display my video stream I load a simple quad and I put my video frame buffer on it like a classical texture mapping. Until here all is ok. But if I add in my scene a simple colored triangle (red, green and blue for my three vertices) the triangle is displayed correctly but my texture is tainted in blue. In fact the API seems to keep the last color loaded for the last vertex of my triangle, so the blue color here. But I don't understand why it keep it.

Here's a screen of the first frame (all is correct):

[image]

And the appearence of the second and the following frames :

[image]

And my c++ rendering code :

```
    getKinectVideoData(_videoData); //Method that fills the video frame buffer for each frame

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (float)width/(float)height, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);


    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)_videoData);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)_videoBuffer->GetBuffer());

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1, -1, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    glVertex3f(-0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
```

I clear the buffer at the begin of each frame using the glClear call so it's very strange.
Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Also, it does work correctly; it just doesn't give you the effect you want `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset the color back to `(255, 255, 255)` (using `glColor`), because it impacts texture processing.

On the first frame, your color is full white, and thus the image is displayed correctly. However, the last call to `glColor` is `(0,0,255)`, and then the loop goes back to the beginning.